# how to calculate centroid of an arraylist of points

Tags: java, arraylist, points, centroid

I am trying to add up all the x and y coordiantes respectively from points of ArrayList.

```
public static ArrayList knots = new ArrayList<Point>();



public Point centroid()  {
        Point center = new Point();
            for(int i=0; i<knots.size(); i++) {
            ????????????????????
        return center;
}
```

How do I find the centroid ??

Comment: what is ???????????????

Comment: Have a look at wikipedia. It is just calculating the center of mass, where you assume a uniform mass density, making the formulas even easier.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
public Point centroid()  {
    double centroidX = 0, centroidY = 0;

        for(Point knot : knots) {
            centroidX += knot.getX();
            centroidY += knot.getY();
        }
    return new Point(centroidX / knots.size(), centroidY / knots.size());
}
```

Comment: is it giving the corret output?

Comment: @mvw This answer has helped this community, if I could downvote your comment I would of.

Comment: @kKarlMorrisson I doubt this strongly. The answer has been awarded upvotes, but it does not even honour the original question (changed loop, changed return statement), the matter of the question (centroid) is very simple and has nothing to do with programming, except how to write down a very easy formula in Java. So I fail to see why anyone except the OP and an unknown group of folks with the same homework has benefitted from this answer.

Comment: well, i have to agree with mvn.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Point centroid()  {
    Point center = new Point();
        int sumofx=0,sumofy=0;
        for(int i=0; i<knots.size(); i++) {
        sumofx= sumofx+knot[i].x;
        sumofy=sumofy+knot[i].y;
        }
    center.x=sumofx/knots.size();
    center.y=sumofy/knots.size();
    return center;
```

}