# How to find a point in the middle of N points?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Let's say I have N points defined by their coordinates (X, Y). How could I find coordinates of another point X, which is in the middle of that N points (i.e. distance between X and each point from N is more or less equal). Is there any algorithm to do it?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain ?

Comment: [Is this similar to your question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130534/given-an-arbitrary-number-of-points-how-do-you-find-an-equidistant-center)

Comment: What does this have to do with programming and or javascript? @YvesDaoust, I suspect downvoted because "any algorithm to do it" screams "off topic for is there a library..[etc]".

Comment: [Seems here is a Java Solution for finding Centroid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591964/how-to-calculate-centroid-of-an-arraylist-of-points)

Comment: Distance between X and others points cannot be equals unless you have a a particular situation (circle). I think you want the centroid ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

Comment: As said in the other post, there is no such point for N>3. The point equidistant to three given ones is uniquely determined as the center of the circumcenter of the triangle, and the remaining N-3 points will occur at different distances.

Comment: @MarcB OP may still be below high school age or not have received formal education. That's no reason to discourage him.

Comment: The very fist part of a downvote says "This question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 2):

You probably mis-stated the question by thinking that a point "in the middle" is equidistant to all others.

As you can't achieve that, a better approach is to minimize the total Euclidean distance of the center to the N points.

It turns out that this problem has no easy analytical solution, as you need to minimize

```
D = Σ √(X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)²
```

Deriving on Xc, you get

```
D'x = Σ (X - Xc) / √(X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)² = 0
```

a complex nonlinear expression. This problem is known as the "geometric median" and you'll find more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) (in particular, the Weiszfeld's algorithm).

On the opposite, minimizing the sum of the *squared* distances

```
D = Σ (X - Xc)² + (Y - Yc)²
```

is trivial as

```
D'x = 2 Σ (X - Xc) = 0
```

which yields the centroid.

```
Xc = Σ X / N, Yc = Σ Y / N.
```

---

You can also think of the *medoid* of your points, which is the point from the given set that minimizes the sum of the distances to the others. It takes `N(N-1)/2` distance computations to find it.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be such a point. You can average the Xs and Ys and get a point that's in the middle (a.k.a "centroid").

Answer (score 1):

For 2 points, this "middle" exists. For more, we can't be sure.

You can calculate the centroid with the average x and y of the points.

```
if (points.length > 0) {
  var x_acc = 0;
  var y_acc = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    x_acc += points[i].x;
    y_acc += points[i].y;
  }

  var centroid_x = x_acc / points.length;
  var centroid_y = y_acc / points.length;
}
```